# Strategy for reverse proxy and certificate renewal

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I am migrating a machine that holds several (`Apache`) websites to a new machine where I want one frontend (I have chosen `nginx`) acting as a reverse proxy and many small `lxc` virtual machines, each dedicated to a specific website.

This is working perfectly in `http` but I now have a problem for certificate renewal : I use certbot/letsencrypt for most of the sites with autorenewal but the reverse proxy does not know about the certificates.

Here are the solutions I see:

- `cron` a copy of the certificates (I don't like the idea because I find it fragile — permissions, renewal failure, etc.)
- install the certificates on the reverse proxy (only) and make plain `http` connections to the various websites. This solution has many advantages: all certificates are in the same place, deployment of new services is simple, etc.

Is this a good solution? Will it work with Wordpress (Wordpress is a real pita regarding URLs)?

Comment: Your second solution seems fine.  If you want to use HTTPS to the individual virtual machine web hosts, you can do that with internal certs / internal CA, but 100% that's significant additional complexity that you don't really need.

Comment: Thanks. It sort-of works but wp-admin insists (ie. redirects/302) on having an https protocol.

Comment: Adding `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);` to `wp-config.php` helps a little (page is accessible) but I get many warnings that the connection is insecure and still no CSS.

Comment: To solve everything:
* on the reverse proxy, add these 2 lines: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";` and `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port "443";`
* in the `wp-config.php` of the wordpress site, add this: `if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https') {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}`. [Find the details here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-behind-reverse-proxy-all-content-insecure/)

Comment: you can use also https on the reverse proxy, nginx don't check for validation or valid certificate,by default. so the certbot has to be on nginx as i use it and the behind nginx does not care about the certification anymore, i use a simple self signed one on the backends